# What are spammers trying to acheive who only provide the correct contact information in their spam?

Tags: ddos, spam, sms

I've recently received 2 spam SMS messages, claiming to be from 2 different organizations, but (obviously) not sent by them.

However, all of the contact details in the SMS match the real details of the organizations in question.

Message 1 from "FraudBureau": Please contact (my financial institution) Fraud Department on (real fraud number available on their website) and press option 3, to confirm card transations. Do not reply.

Message 2 from (a mobile number): Hi, please contact (some company I am not with) on (a number I found on their website also) option 7 at your earliest opportunity regarding an important matter. Quote Ref 40352. Thank you.

They both looked like spam to me, the first looked slightly more legit.

The second organization I called had a recorded greeting at the start saying - "we don't send those messages, don't respond to them.", so they obviously got enough responses to be annoying.

I couldn't find any reference to this phenomenon via a web search.

What is the point of this from the spammers' perspectives? Is it to cause additional load at the legitimate call center? Is it social engineering to make me ignore alerts from my own financial institutions? Something else?

Comment: I would suggest you elaborate on the contents of the message as well as the nature of the two organizations so that we can get a further understanding of the attacker's motives.

Comment: Re. the second company and "_so they obviously got enough responses to be annoying_"... or it's a fake company with a carefully crafted phone message. If pressing "3" were to take you to a real person/spammer, who would try to talk you into something costing you money, the message will filter-out the less gullible (in the same way bad grammar/spelling in spam emails does), leaving the real spammers to concentrate on those most likely to make them money.

Comment: And if "3" just connects you to a premium-rate phone-line, from which they make money, the gullible will probably still do so any way, but _some_ of the people who normally _wouldn't_ press "3" might just do so because they now think they're talking to a real company.

Comment: Thanks @TripeHound, but I don't understand the point you're trying to make. I'm in Australia, and I can tell if a number is mobile or premium from the prefix, so I know the second text was from a mobile, and neither that nor the number it requested I call were premium numbers. I understand the concept of filtering out the skeptical, but given there appeared to be no way for them to collect a payoff, I don't think it applies.

Comment: @Peter The premium-rate could be a red-herring: I've heard stories of people selecting options and somehow being diverted onto premium-rate calls... some of these may be apocryphal, some may have been stopped through better regulation of premium-rate numbers. My **main** point,though, was that even though you found the number on a website, and they have a "_aren't scammers a nuisance_" message, it could still be a fake company. I can see at least two potential ways of collecting a payoff: [**cont**]

Comment: **(a)** the fact someone has called the number marks them as a _potential_ target. Although returning the call _in itself_ might not have a payoff, they now have a targeted list of phone numbers of people that _might_ be susceptible to follow-up scam calls.  **(b)** If someone stays on the line after the recorded message, they'll probably get into a "_yes, we've been plagued with these calls, it's a real nuisance_" conversation, at which point many callers will now "trust" the person they're speaking to, who can launch into selling the real scam ("_while you're on, let me tell you about..._").

Comment: I see this was closed, even though I edited it to add the details that were supposedly missing. A slightly crap experience on this site, IMNSHO, since @ schroeder♦ didn't even add a comment and it is completely impossible to find out what they are complaining about.